# Hidden value from view not being passed to Controller in Symfony 3.4

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

**What I would like:**
I want to have a response form so that when I click on a post in my forum, it adds the form after the selected post. And when I submit the form the selected post or id should be in the form inputs to be able to persist the new comment as an object with valid attribute in Doctrine/ Symfony within my controller.

**What I did:**
I could add the form after the selected element with Jquery. 
I added an hidden input in the form with the same name as the Entity attribute (otherwise Symfony was saying that no such attribute were defined for the entity).
Formbuilder:

```
// other lines of codes
        $formbuilder
            ->add('Parent', HiddenType::class, array('data' => null));
// ….
```

I added an id in the view for each post.(identical to the id in the database / topicarg is my object containing the post’s information)

```
  <button class="btn-info comment" id="{{"#{topicarg.id}"}}"> Answer this post </button> </br>
```

and then I changed the hidden value of the form with Jquery when the user clicks:

```
// ---------------------------------------CREATE ARGUMENTATION FORM AND PUT IT AFTER THE MAIN ARGUMENTATION
  $(".comment").click(function(){
    // Get the ID of the targeted comment in the same element
    var argtargetid =parseInt($(this).attr("id"), 10);

    // CHANGE THE HIDDEN VALUE IN THE FORM WITH THE ID OF THE TARGETED ELEMENT
    $("#formarg_Parent").val(argtargetid);

    // MOVE AND DISPLAY THE FORM
    var argblock = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    $("#formarg").appendTo(argblock);
    $("#formarg").toggle(toggleTime);
  });
```

Here I checked  `$("#formarg_Parent").val(argtargetid);` with an alert and it displays a number as expected.
And finally in my controller I try changing the id of the targeted post with the object corresponding to the id before handling the request.

```
        $contributionid=$formarg->get('Parent')->getData();
        $topicargtarget=$this->getContribution($contributionid);
        $formarg->get('Parent')->setData($topicargtarget);
        $formarg→handleRequest($request);
```

But Symfony returns the following:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to getContribution() must be of the type integer, null given

I could not find the error as, to me, I checked the value in the form with an alert which was satisfaying so it is in the form ready to be passed to the controller, I get it in the controller and change it into an object. But something is wrong obviously in my method or syntax.
Thank you for your time helping me !

Comment: What do you get from var_dump($topicargtarget); die(); ?

Comment: I cannot do var_dump() on topicargtarget as the problem is with the getContribution method that needs something not null to work with.  But i did it on $contributionid and it gave me NULL. Which means that the value is not submitted with the other form values, right ?

Comment: You use a getter instead of setter. `getContribution` should be `setContribution`

Comment: it should be a getter as I want to have the  "Contribution" that matches the targeted id given by the hidden value in the form. The setter is setData, where I insert the object where before I had id, just before handling the request. Although the problem I mention is before with no value being passed from the view to the controller, your comment makes me think that I have another problem coming. I should not use the setData of the form with an object but instead directly hydrate the object with its setter before persist.

Comment: @Shaker81 maybe you need to use $form['Parent']->getData(); to get the value?

Comment: @Vyctorya thanks for the suggestion but it also did not work. The value I get is still null. I changed the hidden value property to mapped => false so as it is not linked with the entity but did not change anything also. I have really no idea where the error comes from. And it doesn't look like bad practice but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I realized that I was trying to extract a data from the form before I even handled it. So it was just an empty form that is why I always got NULL. So I had to do `$contributionid=$formarg->get('Parent')->getData()` after `handlerequest()`.
The only thing was that Symfony was not allowing me to do so as the property in the field parent was not an instance of the Contribution object. To avoid that I had to add the option `mapped => false` in the construction of my form to tell symfony that this property did not have to be mapped with the object. Then the id was passed to the controller, not mapped to the object and I could change the id in an instance of Contribution in order to persist the new Contribution (or post) 
So now it works !**Thank you all for your time and help. It helped me figuring things out !**

Answer (score -1):

If I get you right, what you are looking for is  *CollectionType Field*.

3.4:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Current:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: I would like to pass the id of the targeted post to the controller. Before I was using a separate page, so I could put this id in the route. Now I would like to do everything in one page, but without AJAX as don't know how it works yet. So I don't know how the Collection Field could help. But maybe I do not see something you see?